# How to get a list of gap dates

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a db table storing values with a day (in datetime). Now I would like to find those days where no entry int he table exists.

Example:

```
2011-11-15 00:00:00 | 10.00
2011-11-17 00:00:00 | 20.00
2011-11-18 00:00:00 | 30.00
```

2011-11-16 00:00:00 is missing, so this date would be the one that should be returned from the SELECT statement.

I tried

```
WITH days(d) AS (
SELECT i::timestamp(0) 
FROM generate_series('2011-11-16 00:00:00', '2015-08-09 13:00:00', interval '1 day') d(i)
)
SELECT d FROM 
days
LEFT JOIN tgeg_maand ON d = Datum_Maand
WHERE tgeg_maand IS NULL;
```

but MySQL does not seem to understand the "WITH" statement.

Thanks a lot and sorry if the question is too simple!

Comment: You need a calendar table

Comment: so you need query to  fetch result from database where dates NOT exist?

Comment: define "identify". What exact output are you looking for? (And what exact SQL flavor are you using?)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? In Postgres `generate_series()` comes in handy for this kind of tasks

Comment: It's mySql and I extended my question.

Comment: with is not  supported in mysql though..:p

Comment: Either construct a calendar table/some kind of utility table/a sequence of integer unions or handle the logic of missing dates in your application level code e.g. a bit of php

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged MySQL, but your syntax is Postgres.  One way you can do what you want in MySQL (or any other database) is using `not exists`:

```
select m.*
from tgeg_maand m
where not exists (select 1
                  from tgeg_maand m2
                  where m.Datum_Maand = date_add(m2.Datum_Maand, interval 1 day)
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from tgeg_maand m2
              where m2.Datum_Maand < m.Datum_Maand
             );
```

The first condition (`not exists`) says that there are no records on the previous day.  The second condition simply filters out the first record.  For performance, you would want an index on `tgeg_maand(Datum_Maand)`.  Note:  there are other similar ways to express the same logic.

Comment: Hi Gordon, there is one ")" missing at the end...   ;-)   I tried this and received an unexpected result. I do see rows that all have values for field "Datum_Maand" AND "Geg_Maand" (which is the field for the values). Strange....